# UIActivityViewController not showing Built-in activities

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using a UIActivityViewController with just some of the Apple built-in services.  As a test, I specify no excludedActivityTypes (the docs say this is nil by default) and no completion handler (I just want the services to do their thing).

I'm building using Xcode/SDK Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)

```
// this is the handler that catches the Action button tap
// self.noteArea.text is the UITextView.text string to use by the services.
- (IBAction)actionTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithString:self.noteArea.text];
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObject:s];
    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:a applicationActivities:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

On both the simulator and a real iPhone the activity popup shows only Mail and Copy -- nothing else.  Why just those two?  Mail and Copy work fine, so everything that does show seems to work properly.  How do I get the other functions to display?

Comment: What others do you expect to see for a string? Activities like Facebook and Twitter will only appear if you have setup accounts for those in the Settings app. Do you have such accounts setup?

Comment: i'm not interested in Facebook or Twitter so I will have them in the excludedActivites list.  But in this case I have no excludedActivites list.  The specific icon I expect to see in the (iPhone) popup is Print.  Do I need to set up something in order for the Print icon to be included?